# How to consolidate all applicable projects and nuget packages from the command line?

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I'm merging two solutions and now have the following situation

[image]

[image]

It is a large project and consolidating a single package takes enough time. Consolidating 26 and I'll be here all day. Is there a way to batch consolidate so I can go an have lunch and it will be done when I get back?

Comment: I had the same situation with nuget in VS2015. It was almost unusable as we had 80 projects per solution and each continuous build was creating 5 dependencies for these projects and it was taking 30 minutes to update them all. We ended up writing an application that finds the latest dependencies and override project.json files with newest versions manually and then calls nuget restore. You can consider doing something similar (I suspect it's new csproj now, so it can be a little harder). Strange, Nuget Team said that performance was drastically improved in VS2017...

Comment: Nuget team always says performance is fine. I've never understood what goes on. It is a minor scale optimization problem that should be able to be solved in about half a second. Yet I'm waiting now for 10 minutes just for one of my consolidation packages to update over 30 projects.

Comment: I was recommended to upgrade my projects to the new PackageReference code because that would be sooooo much faster. But still solving one consolidation is taking 15 minutes.

Comment: if you are using project.json I would recommend you to write a tool that finds all project.json files in a specific directory (solution) and read dependencies and then updates them to the latest version. It's pretty straightforward to use nuget API to get the latest deps and replace them in project.json files. Updating 5 dependencies in 80 projects takes 0 time for replacement + about 1-2 minutes to install with build. If you update dependencies in project.json files then you don't even have to call nuget restore because it's done automatically by vs during the build.

Comment: @MistyK perhaps you could post your "tool" as the answer?

Comment: @BozoJoe Here you are. Please ask me if you need further explanation.

Comment: WHY IT TAKE SO LONG? Any tricks just to speed it consolidation?

Comment: Use sync-package command as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792624/how-to-enforce-same-nuget-package-version-across-multiple-c-sharp-projects/71934573#71934573

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enforce same nuget package version across multiple c# projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792624/how-to-enforce-same-nuget-package-version-across-multiple-c-sharp-projects)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the comments I'll post my solution here. It's a part of a bigger tool so I'll post key class here, it should be pretty straightforward to connect it together.
Installed packages (you can probably use newer versions):

```
"NuGet.Core": "2.12.0-rtm-815",
"NuGet.Packaging": "3.5.0-beta2-1484",
"NuGet.ProjectManagement": "3.5.0-beta2-1484",
```

Source:

```
public class NugetSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyAppVersion
{
    public double Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Dependency> Dependencies { get; set; }

    public MyAppVersion()
    {
        Dependencies = new ObservableCollection<Dependency>();
    }
}

public class Dependency : ReactiveObject
{
    public Dependency()
    {
        AvailableVersions = new List<SemanticVersion>();
    }

    private SemanticVersion _version;
    private string _name;
    private List<SemanticVersion> _availableVersions;

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public SemanticVersion Version
    {
        get { return _version; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _version, value); }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<SemanticVersion> AvailableVersions
    {
        get { return _availableVersions; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _availableVersions, value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name}, Version: {Version}";
    }
}

public class NugetUpdater : INugetUpdater
{
    private readonly List<IPackageRepository> _supportedRepositories;

    public NugetUpdater()
    {
        _supportedRepositories =
            GetSources().Select(x => PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(x.Value)).ToList();
    }

    public NugetSource[] GetSources()
    {

        var sources = new[]
        {
            new NugetSource() {Name = nameof(AppPaths.Dev), Value = AppPaths.Dev},
            new NugetSource() {Name = nameof(AppPaths.Uat), Value = AppPaths.Uat},
            new NugetSource() {Name = nameof(AppPaths.ThirdParty), Value = AppPaths.ThirdParty},
        };

        return sources;
    }

    public List<SemanticVersion> GetVersions(IEnumerable<string> feedUrls, string packageId)
    {
        var versions = new List<SemanticVersion>();
        var repos = GetRepositories(feedUrls);

        foreach (var currentRepo in repos)
        {
            var packages = currentRepo.FindPackagesById(packageId).ToList();
            versions.AddRange(packages.Select(x => x.Version));
        }

        return versions;
    }

    public SemanticVersion GetLatestVersion(IEnumerable<string> feedUrls, string packageId)
    {
        var versions = GetVersions(feedUrls, packageId);
        return versions.Any() ? versions.Max() : null;
    }

    public SemanticVersion GetLatestVersion(string feedUrl, string packageId)
    {
        return GetLatestVersion(new[] {feedUrl}, packageId);
    }

    public List<SemanticVersion> GetVersions(string feedUrl, string packageId)
    {
        return GetVersions(new[] {feedUrl}, packageId);
    }

    public List<Dependency> GetSolutionDependencies(string baseDir)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDir, "project.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(File.ReadAllText)
            .Select(JObject.Parse)
            .Select(GetDependencies)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .DistinctBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
    }

    private List<IPackageRepository> GetRepositories(IEnumerable<string> feedUrls)
    {
        return _supportedRepositories.Where(x => feedUrls.Contains(x.Source)).ToList();
    }

    public void Update(string baseDir, MyAppVersion version)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> jsonFiles =
            Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDir, "project.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (var projectJsonPath in jsonFiles)
        {
            var content = File.ReadAllText(projectJsonPath);
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
            var projectDependencies = GetDependencies(json);

            if (!projectDependencies.Any())
                continue;

            var projectDepNames = projectDependencies.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            var toUpdateDependencies = version.Dependencies.Where(x => projectDepNames.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

            if (toUpdateDependencies.Count != projectDependencies.Count)
                throw new Exception("Dependencies count is not equal. Something went wrong");

            var dependenciesPairs = toUpdateDependencies.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .Zip(projectDependencies.OrderBy(x => x.Name), (x, y) => new {ToUpdate = x, Project = y}).ToList();


            bool anyChanged = false;

            foreach (var dependencyPair in dependenciesPairs)
            {
                if (dependencyPair.Project.Version != dependencyPair.ToUpdate.Version)
                {
                    anyChanged = true;
                    dependencyPair.Project.Version = dependencyPair.ToUpdate.Version;
                }
            }

            if (anyChanged)
            {
                JObject obj = new JObject(projectDependencies.Select(x => new JProperty(x.Name, x.Version.ToNormalizedString())));
                json["dependencies"] = obj;
                File.WriteAllText(projectJsonPath, json.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Dependency> GetDependencies(JObject json)
    {
        JObject dependenciesObject = (JObject) json["dependencies"];

        var dependencies = dependenciesObject.Properties().Select(x => new Dependency
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Version = SemanticVersion.Parse(x.Value.Value<string>())
        }).ToList();

        return dependencies;
    }
}
```

Basically application uses `NugetUpdater` `GetSolutionDependencies` to display to the user all dependencies in a solution.

Then `GetVersions` method is used to get available versions for the selected package. User can select the version he is interested in. When he finishes he clicks update and `Update` function will use user selected versions to replace all dependencies in all project.jsons in a solution.

Instead of selecting the versions one by one, user can select latest versions for all packages, it's pretty easy with combination of

`GetSolutionDependencies` + `GetLatestVersion` for each single package + `Update`.

Basically the result is a list of project.json's updated with the latest versions of packages.

All you have to do is either run `nuget restore` or build the solution with VS which will automatically call restore.

Comment: The `DistinctBy` requires the ["MoreLinq" NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).

Comment: @UweKeim, not really, I wouldn't install the whole package just for one function. It can be implemented pretty easily with HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no button for "Consolidate All" and I think there's a good reason why Microsoft hasn't added it, which I only just realized myself when dealing with this exact issue for the last few weeks.

There's no way for the system to automatically know *how* you want to consolidate the packages. Do you want to upgrade everything to the same version or downgrade some things?

If you just want to upgrade everything to the same version, there's an Upgrade all option, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: it's a  b..llsh..t. If you have a button like consolidate all it means that you want ALL libraries to move to the same version. And if some library doesn't have latest version, it say: sorry, this library has no updates.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the Solution in VS, you can select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions". On the Updates Tab, you can check the box for "Select All Packages" and then Update. This will effectively consolidate all your packages between the projects by updating them all to the latest version.