# .net core 2.2.0 vs 2.2.7 cannot consolidate, because versions locked by project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, multiple-versions

I have a Visual Studio solution relying on .net core 2.2. Once updated to sdk 2.2.7, only one project depends on SDK->Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7; the other projects keeps referring to SDK->Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0.

Going in nuget manager, Consolidate tab, it is not possible to align the versions between projects because "locked by project" (see below).

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Lorenzo

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to mix 2.2.0 and 2.2.7. You should always target what is the latest of 2.2 release so that remain supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi Lance. I was out of office, sorry for the late reply. Yes, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Lex Li, yes it is nonesense to mix, but it was not my choice. It depended on installing more recent SDK, that VS managed "on its own", updating only 1 project in the whole solution...

Comment: "Consolidate" tab And Sync-Package were discussing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792624/how-to-enforce-same-nuget-package-version-across-multiple-c-sharp-projects/71934573#71934573 question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 cannot update Microsoft.NETCore.App package ("Blocked by project")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026190/visual-studio-2017-cannot-update-microsoft-netcore-app-package-blocked-by-proj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Going in nuget manager, Consolidate tab, it is not possible to align
>   the versions between projects because "locked by project" (see below).

See [Consolidate tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#consolidate-tab), this option can't work when one project in your solution don't support being updated.

For those `.net core` and `asp.net core` projects,by default they use the version 2.2.0, and it's not supported to consolidate them by `manage packages for solution` or update it by `manage packages for project`, we have to update those projects one-by-one following the steps:

1.Right-click the project=>Edit `xxx.csproj`

2.If there exists statement like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" />`, explicitly add the version 2.2.0 to it: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />`. If there not exists such statement, add it manually.

3.Then now right-click the project=>Manage nuget packages, you can choose the 2.2.7 version to update.

Note: It requires us to install the corresponding sdk and runtime in machine. And according to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031957/10910450)'s answer, in most cases you never need to update the blocked projects,please check if you have specific reason to update or consolidate it.